# Can an immortal character be killed permanently?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-death

In the Exalted Angel epic destiny (Divine Power p.154), a player's character has its origin changed to 'Immortal', and at level 24, gains the 'Reborn in Light' feature where, upon its first death per day, the character explodes into light and later reforms at the end of the encounter, fully healed. My question is what happens if this character dies a second time that day? Does its Immortal origin mean it returns to life the next day?

As far as I'm aware, taking this ED makes the character an angel in all respects, so the same rules should apply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Immortal origin means that a creature will no die to old age, but they can still be killed by other methods. From the compendium:

> Immortal creatures are native to the Astral Sea. Unless they are killed, they live forever.

If the character would die a second time they would be dead until a Raise Dead ritual was used or some other method was used to raise them. The ability only happens once per day, once you use it to not die once in a day you cannot use it again until the next day.

Note that while this ED does make you very angel like, it does not actually make you an angel.